# SQLite3 not saving records once program closed

Tags: tkinter, sqlite

I am using the code below to try and work in TKinter with SQLite3 and Pi.  This is a completely new area to me.  When I run the code I see the records in the database, when I close the connection and reconnect they are gone.  I added the close and reconnect as when I closed the program they were also not there.

The table is still there as if I remove the IF NOT EXISTS it returns the error, the table already exists, but there are no records! Am I missing something obvious!

```
import sqlite3

conn=sqlite3.connect("CFAccountsTest.db")
c=conn.cursor()

def openwindow():
global window
window=Tk()    
window.title("MMS")
window.geometry("200x100")
window.resizable(False,False)
window.configure(background="light blue")
frame_entry = Frame(window)
frame_entry.grid(columnspan=2,padx=70,pady=5)

c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test(User TEXT)')
x="J"
c.execute('INSERT INTO Test (User) VALUES (?)',x)
x="T"
c.execute('INSERT INTO Test (User) VALUES (?)',x)
conn.commit
print ("I Have added")
sql = "SELECT * FROM Test"
c.execute(sql)
print (c.fetchall())    #THIS SHOWS THE 2 RECORDS 
conn.close

#New Connection
Xconn=sqlite3.connect("CFAccountsTest.db")
Xc=Xconn.cursor()

print ("New Connection Show Table")
sql = "SELECT * FROM Test"
Xc.execute(sql)
print (Xc.fetchall()) #THIS SHOWS NO RECORDS
```

Comment: `con.commit` is not doing what you think it does. It needs to be `con.commit()`. Not sure if that's _the_ problem, but it's definitely _a_ problem. Likewise for the `close` method.

Comment: Also, you need to fix the indentation, and create a [mcve]. Your code is missing some important statements, such as how you import tkinter and how/when you call `openwindow`.

Comment: Bryan Oakley, Thanks so much, () sorted the problem